# Rundeck - Execute ansible playbook on a remote ansible server

Tags: rundeck

New in Rundeck
What i'm trying to achieve with rundeck is the following -
to let a windows user connect rundeck and execute predefined ansible playbooks that are located on a remote ansible server. Doing this will not require the user to connect the ansible server (i dont need to share password) and only approved user that can login to rundeck can run the scripts

Is it possible to install Rundeck on a windows machine and execute ansible scripts that are located on a remote ansible server?

Can i see the playbook output on rundeck UI?

If not, should I run rundeck on the local ansible server?

Can i have all the above using the community Rundeck version ?

Answer (score 0):

By design Rundeck and Ansible must coexist in the same server to use the Ansible [plugin](https://github.com/Batix/rundeck-ansible-plugin) but, you can dispatch Ansible commands (`ansible-playbook`) on remote servers using the [command step](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#command-step).